# Changing Image Height is Opposite Value; winForm

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, user-interface, c++-cli

I'm creating a custom installer and working on the progress bar. I have a timer function that increments the specified rectangle's Height property by +1.

```
statusBar->Height += 1;
    if (statusBar->Height >= 285)
    {
        StatusBarTimer->Stop();
    }
```

However, the origin point of the shape seems to be located in the top left of the shape, and therefore the Height acts opposite of its controls. I.E. the rectangle extends it's height the opposite direction of where I would like to.

[customInstaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtD0J.png)
(*See arrowed object*)

Is there a work-around for this, or better yet, is there a way to change the origin point of an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All common modern GUI toolkits position their controls top-down and left-right. The position you specify will be the top-left corner of the control, the size will extend downward and to the right.

If you want a control to grow upward, adjust the top and the height at the same time. Or use an existing progress bar control that supports being vertical.

Comment: Unfortunate that that is how things work. The solution I found was to change the height and Location (Y) simultaneously, to give the illusion that it raising positively. Thank you.